# Пирамидальное возведение в квадрат больших чисел

Tags: c, алгоритм, ассемблер, математика

Есть алгоритм быстрого возведения в квадрат произвольных чисел в системе счисления по основанию b (не обязательно `b = 2` или `b = 2^k`). Этот алгоритм далее используется при возведении в степень методом последовательного возведения в квадрат и в идеале должен работать даже с 2048-битными числами. У меня не получается его реализовать, я не знаю, как хранить эти числа, как извлекать из них цифры, как умножать такие числа при помощи сдвигов, как вычислять пары и тройки (u, v) и (c, u, v).

Использование переноса намекает на удобство реализации на ассемблере, но совершенно непонятно, как организовать данные в этом алгоритме, и как выполнить пункт 2.3.

Попытка реализации:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Вход: массив цифр числа x по основанию b
// Выход: массив y длины 2 * xlen, содержащий цифры x^2
// b - основание системы счисления, xlen - длина массива x
void fast_square(char x[], char y[], int b, int xlen)
{
    int i, j, c, u, v;
    int uv, cuv;

    for(i = 0; i <= 2*xlen - 1; i++)
        y[i] = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        uv = y[2 * i] + x[i] * x[i];
        y[2 * i] = uv % d;  // uv % b - последняя цифра числа (u, v)
        u = uv / b; // Из числа uv удалили цифру v и сохранили u
        for(j = i + 1; j <= xlen - 1; j++)
        {
            // Здесь (c*b + u) равно числу (c, u) в СС с осн. b
            cuv = y[i + j] + 2 * x[i] * x[j] + (c*b + u);
            y[i + j] = cuv % b; // Последняя цифра v числа cuv
        }
    }
}

int main(){

}
```

Алгоритм: [ссылка](http://ido.tsu.ru/iop_res1/teorcrypto/text/1_3.html)
Еще одна [ссылка на рсдн, где пытались написать реализацию, но не написали](http://rsdn.ru/forum/alg/1532697.all)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Т. к. вы пытаетесь добиться лучшей производительности, то могу посоветовать использовать `unsigned int` вместо `char` - единицей вычисления является машинное слово, а не один байт, к тому же при использовании знакового типа могут возникнуть проблемы. Для хранения использовать массив. Для арифметических операций представьте как это всё вычисляет машина, придётся это реализовать через "умножение(и не только) в столбик", самому следить за переносами и прочим.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPD 26.10.2017**

### Вывод алгоритма

Известно, что:

Квадрат суммы нескольких чисел - это сумма их квадратов, плюс удвоенная сумма всех их попарных произведений

Квадрат бита **(0 | 1)** равен этому биту

Пусть **n = b<sub>0</sub>2<sup>0</sup> + b<sub>1</sub>2<sup>1</sup> + b<sub>2</sub>2<sup>2</sup> + ... + b<sub>i-1</sub>2<sup>i-1</sup>,**
тогда **n<sup>2</sup> = (b<sub>0</sub>2<sup>0</sup> + b<sub>1</sub>2<sup>1</sup> + b<sub>2</sub>2<sup>2</sup> + ... + b<sub>i-1</sub>2<sup>i-1</sup>)<sup>2</sup>**, где **i** - разрядность числа **n**.

**n<sup>2</sup> = b<sub>0</sub>2<sup>0</sup> + b<sub>1</sub>2<sup>2</sup> + b<sub>2</sub>2<sup>4</sup> + ... + b<sub>i-1</sub>2<sup>2i-2</sup> + b<sub>0</sub>4<sup>1</sup>(b<sub>1</sub>2<sup>0</sup> + b<sub>2</sub>2<sup>1</sup> + b<sub>3</sub>2<sup>2</sup>
 + ... + b<sub>i-1</sub>2<sup>i-2</sup>) + b<sub>1</sub>4<sup>2</sup>(b<sub>2</sub>2<sup>0</sup> + b<sub>3</sub>2<sup>1</sup> + b<sub>4</sub>2<sup>2</sup> + ... + b<sub>i-1</sub>2<sup>i-3</sup>) + b<sub>2</sub>4<sup>3</sup>(b<sub>3</sub>2<sup>0</sup> + b<sub>4</sub>2<sup>1</sup> + b<sub>5</sub>2<sup>2</sup> + ... + b<sub>i-1</sub>2<sup>i-4</sup>) + ... + b<sub>i-2</sub>4<sup>i-1</sup>b<sub>i-1</sub>**,
**n<sup>2</sup> = b<sub>0</sub>((1 << 0) | (n >> 1) << 2) + b<sub>1</sub>((1 << 1) | (n >> 2) << 4) + b<sub>2</sub>((1 << 2) | (n >> 3) << 6) + ...

+ b<sub>i-2</sub>((1 << (i-2) | (n >> (i-1)) << (2i-2)) + b<sub>i-1</sub>((1 << (i-1) | (n >> i) << (2i).**

Пусть **j<sub>k</sub> = ((2n) >> k)**, тогда **b<sub>k</sub> = ((j<sub>k+1</sub> & 1) > 0) = ((j<sub>k</sub> & 2 > 0)**,

**n<sup>2</sup> = (j<sub>0</sub> & 2 ? (1 << 0) | (j<sub>2</sub> << 2) : 0) + (j<sub>1</sub> & 2 ? (1 << 1) | (j<sub>3</sub> << 4) : 0)
+ (j<sub>2</sub> & 1 ? (1 << 2) | (j<sub>4</sub> << 6) : 0) + ... + (j<sub>i-2</sub> & 2 ? (1 << (i-2)) | (j<sub>i</sub> << (2i-2) : 0) + (j<sub>i-1</sub> & 2 ? (1 << (i-1) | (j<sub>i+1</sub> << (2i) : 0)**.

Однако **j<sub>k+2</sub> << 2 = (j<sub>k</sub> >> 2) << 2 = j<sub>k</sub> &  0b111...100 = j<sub>k</sub> & (-4)** (сброс нулевого и первого битов), поэтому:

**n<sup>2</sup> = (j<sub>0</sub> & 2 ? (j<sub>0</sub> & -4 | 1) << 0 : 0) + (j<sub>1</sub> & 2 ? (j<sub>1</sub> & -4 | 1) << 2 : 0)
+ (j<sub>2</sub> & 1 ? (j<sub>2</sub> & -4 | 1) << 4 : 0) + ... + (j<sub>i-2</sub> & 2 ? (j<sub>i-2</sub> & -4 | 1) << (2i-4) : 0) + (j<sub>i-1</sub> & 2 ? (j<sub>i-1</sub> & -4 | 1) << (2i -2) : 0)**.

### Программная реализация для чисел формата integer

В программе (на языке PHP) алгоритм пирамидального возведения в квадрат реализован в виде функции `pow2()` и протестирован для чисел формата integer. Функция `pow2($i)` в `2.5` раза проигрывает по времени стандартной процедуре `pow($i, 2)`, использующей аппаратное умножение, что можно считать хорошим результатом. В 64-битовой версии PHP7 проигрыш больше (~10 раз).

Текст программы:

```
define("N", 99);  // Количество точек в тестовом массиве.
define("PR", 1);  // PR=0 - тест производительности.

// Вывод одномерного массива
function print_1d($text, $v){
    $eps = 1e-7;
    print "$text"."[";
    $cnt = -1;
    foreach($v as $key => $item){
        if(++$cnt) print ",&emsp;";
        $flag = true;
        if($cnt && !($cnt%5)) print"<br>";
        print "&quot;$key&quot;=>";
        if(abs((int)$item - $item) > $eps){
            printf("%.3f", $item);
        }else{
            print $item;
        }
    } 
    print "], ";
}

// Пирамидальное возведение в квадрат
function pow2($n){
    if($n < 0) $n = -$n;
    $res = 0;
    for($j = $n << 1, $sh = 0; $j > 1; $j >>= 1, $sh += 2){
        $res += ($j & 2) ? ($j & -4 | 1) << $sh : 0;
    }
    return $res;
}

$test = [];
for($i = 0; $i < N; $i++){
    $test[] = mt_rand(-9999, 9999); 
}

$time_start = microtime(true);
$pow2_ = [];
for($i = 0; $i < N; $i++){
    $pow2_[$test[$i]] = pow2($test[$i]); 
}
$time1 = microtime(true) - $time_start;

$time_start = microtime(true);
$pow2__ = [];
for($i = 0; $i < N; $i++){
    $pow2__[$test[$i]] = pow($test[$i], 2); 
}
$time2 = microtime(true) - $time_start;

printf("Возведение в квадрат  для N = %d случайных точек", (int)N);
if(PR > 0){
    print_1d("<br>*** Пирамидальный алгоритм ***<br>Результаты:<br>", $pow2_);
    print_1d("<br>*** Библиотечный алгоритм ***<br>Результаты:<br>", $pow2__);
}else{
    print("<br>*** Пирамидальный алгоритм ***<br>Время выполнения: $time1");
    print("<br>*** Библиотечный алгоритм ***<br>Время выполнения: $time2");
}
```

Проверка на случайной выборке:

```
Возведение в квадрат для N = 99 случайных точек
*** Пирамидальный алгоритм ***
Результаты:
["8154"=>66487716, "993"=>986049, "-3669"=>13461561, "7855"=>61701025, "-7597"=>57714409, 
"1568"=>2458624, "-9029"=>81522841, "-6646"=>44169316, "-4934"=>24344356, "-3954"=>15634116, 
"-5303"=>28121809, "70"=>4900, "1661"=>2758921, "-3628"=>13162384, "5734"=>32878756, 
"4802"=>23059204, "-1886"=>3556996, "4269"=>18224361, "9638"=>92891044, "-7879"=>62078641, 
"9218"=>84971524, "-2221"=>4932841, "-7153"=>51165409, "5861"=>34351321, "-3656"=>13366336, 
"3058"=>9351364, "-8879"=>78836641, "593"=>351649, "329"=>108241, "-4801"=>23049601, 
"-8637"=>74597769, "4480"=>20070400, "9918"=>98366724, "8584"=>73685056, "-8525"=>72675625, 
"1920"=>3686400, "5019"=>25190361, "8697"=>75637809, "-5594"=>31292836, "-8198"=>67207204, 
"-7119"=>50680161, "-6288"=>39538944, "131"=>17161, "320"=>102400, "-5410"=>29268100, 
"9147"=>83667609, "-7411"=>54922921, "-2211"=>4888521, "3990"=>15920100, "-2077"=>4313929, 
"-6588"=>43401744, "-9280"=>86118400, "7357"=>54125449, "-1909"=>3644281, "6109"=>37319881, 
"911"=>829921, "8898"=>79174404, "-4262"=>18164644, "6537"=>42732369, "-3567"=>12723489, 
"1345"=>1809025, "-9229"=>85174441, "6654"=>44275716, "-9949"=>98982601, "9057"=>82029249, 
"-8760"=>76737600, "779"=>606841, "-9905"=>98109025, "45"=>2025, "-8160"=>66585600, 
"-6796"=>46185616, "-5270"=>27772900, "8019"=>64304361, "-1922"=>3694084, "1542"=>2377764, 
"-2489"=>6195121, "-4835"=>23377225, "4752"=>22581504, "-9621"=>92563641, "782"=>611524, 
"6617"=>43784689, "4506"=>20304036, "-7679"=>58967041, "-1476"=>2178576, "-6194"=>38365636, 
"-4385"=>19228225, "7394"=>54671236, "1323"=>1750329, "870"=>756900, "-6723"=>45198729, 
"4162"=>17322244, "-5436"=>29550096, "-7761"=>60233121, "-596"=>355216, "-7463"=>55696369, 
"356"=>126736, "429"=>184041, "-1011"=>1022121, "9811"=>96255721], 
*** Библиотечный алгоритм ***
Результаты:
["8154"=>66487716, "993"=>986049, "-3669"=>13461561, "7855"=>61701025, "-7597"=>57714409, 
"1568"=>2458624, "-9029"=>81522841, "-6646"=>44169316, "-4934"=>24344356, "-3954"=>15634116, 
"-5303"=>28121809, "70"=>4900, "1661"=>2758921, "-3628"=>13162384, "5734"=>32878756, 
"4802"=>23059204, "-1886"=>3556996, "4269"=>18224361, "9638"=>92891044, "-7879"=>62078641, 
"9218"=>84971524, "-2221"=>4932841, "-7153"=>51165409, "5861"=>34351321, "-3656"=>13366336, 
"3058"=>9351364, "-8879"=>78836641, "593"=>351649, "329"=>108241, "-4801"=>23049601, 
"-8637"=>74597769, "4480"=>20070400, "9918"=>98366724, "8584"=>73685056, "-8525"=>72675625, 
"1920"=>3686400, "5019"=>25190361, "8697"=>75637809, "-5594"=>31292836, "-8198"=>67207204, 
"-7119"=>50680161, "-6288"=>39538944, "131"=>17161, "320"=>102400, "-5410"=>29268100, 
"9147"=>83667609, "-7411"=>54922921, "-2211"=>4888521, "3990"=>15920100, "-2077"=>4313929, 
"-6588"=>43401744, "-9280"=>86118400, "7357"=>54125449, "-1909"=>3644281, "6109"=>37319881, 
"911"=>829921, "8898"=>79174404, "-4262"=>18164644, "6537"=>42732369, "-3567"=>12723489, 
"1345"=>1809025, "-9229"=>85174441, "6654"=>44275716, "-9949"=>98982601, "9057"=>82029249, 
"-8760"=>76737600, "779"=>606841, "-9905"=>98109025, "45"=>2025, "-8160"=>66585600, 
"-6796"=>46185616, "-5270"=>27772900, "8019"=>64304361, "-1922"=>3694084, "1542"=>2377764, 
"-2489"=>6195121, "-4835"=>23377225, "4752"=>22581504, "-9621"=>92563641, "782"=>611524, 
"6617"=>43784689, "4506"=>20304036, "-7679"=>58967041, "-1476"=>2178576, "-6194"=>38365636, 
"-4385"=>19228225, "7394"=>54671236, "1323"=>1750329, "870"=>756900, "-6723"=>45198729, 
"4162"=>17322244, "-5436"=>29550096, "-7761"=>60233121, "-596"=>355216, "-7463"=>55696369, 
"356"=>126736, "429"=>184041, "-1011"=>1022121, "9811"=>96255721],
```

Тестирование быстродействия (PHP5):

```
Возведение в квадрат для N = 100000 случайных точек
*** Пирамидальный алгоритм ***
Время выполнения: 1.29107379913
*** Библиотечный алгоритм ***
Время выполнения: 0.49302816391
```

### Рекомендации для алгоритма больших чисел

Работа с большими числами ограничивается следующим небольшим фрагментом:

```
    for($j = 2*$n, $sh = 0; $j > 1; $j >>= 1, $sh += 2){
        if($j & 2){
            $res += ($j ^ 3 | 1) << $sh;
        }
    }
```

Рекомендации для больших чисел:

1. Формат чисел - двоичный. При использовании массива слов возникнут проблемы со знаковыми битами и хранением реальной длины числа. Более гибким является символьный формат с кодированием и декодированием через функции `chr()` и `ord()`, поскольку в нём имеется доступ к каждому байту.
2. При сравнении `$j > 1` достаточно длины чисел в битах. При тестировании бита `$j & $2` и формировании нулевого и первого битов достаточно использовать только младший фрагмент числа.
3. Операции сдвига и суммирования для `$n` должны быть реализованы в полном объёме.