# Вычислить сумму

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дана последовательность целых чисел `x1,...,xn`.

Как эффективно вычислить такую сумму `(x1*x2 + x1*x3 + ... + x1*xn) + (x2*x3 + x2*x4 + ... + x2*xn) + ... + (xn-2 * xn-1 + xn-2*xn) + (xn-1*xn)` ?

Comment: выносим подобные за скобки и вычисляем...

Answer (score 10):

В качестве ещё одного варианта, давайте рассмотрим квадратную таблицу

```
x1*x1  x1*x2  x1*x3  ...  x1*xn
x2*x1  x2*x2  x2*x3  ...  x2*xn
 ...    ...    ...   ...   ...
xn*x1  xn*x2  xn*x3  ...  xn*xn
```

Ваша сумма — это сумма всех чисел над главной диагональю, а также сумма всех чисел под главной диагональю (они одинаковы). Поэтому искомая сумма равна сумме всех чисел таблицы минус сумма чисел на главной диагонали, и всё вместе ещё поделить на 2.

Сумма чисел на главной диагонали — это `x1 * x1 + x2 * x2 + ... + xn * xn`. (`n` умножений, `n - 1` сложение).

А сумма всех чисел таблицы — это просто сумма всех возможных попарных произведений чисел `xi` и `xj`, то есть это просто `(x1 + x2 + ... + xn) * (x1 + x2 + ... + xn)`. (Можно легко убедиться, раскрыв скобки.) Таким образом, сумма чисел в таблице вычисляется за `n - 1` сложение и одно умножение.

Итого получается `2n - 2` сложений, `n + 1` умножение и одно деление на 2 (ну или умножение на 0.5, если хотите).

Comment: Это полиномиальная формула для квадратов=)

Comment: Минус, пожалуй, один - бОльшая вероятность переполнения... Три лишних умножения не в счет :)

Comment: Я [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/640651/195342) немного посравнивал... :)

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Она самая, но поскольку далеко не все её знают, я написал вывод формулы.

Comment: (n+1) возведение в квадрат. Для длинных чисел допускает оптимизацию: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495557/%d0%9f%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb/497019#497019

Answer (score 6):

Ну, может, так?

```
int sum = 0;
int part = 0;

for(int i = n; i > 1; --i)
{
    sum += x[i-1]*(part += x[i]);
}
```

Судя по отсутствию реакции, осталось непонятно :)

Сначала вычисляется и прибавляется к `sum` значение `x[n-1]*x[n]` и `part` становится `x[n-1]+x[n]`

Затем вычисляется и прибавляется к `sum` значение `x[n-2]*(x[n-1]+x[n])`, а `part` становится равным `x[n-2]+x[n-1]+x[n]`...

Словом, вычисляем с конца, наращивая сумму. Получается `n-1` умножений и `2n-2` сложений.

Answer (score 5):

Интересно сравнить варианты @VladD и мой (VC++ 2015).

Вот сравниловка:

```
using number = double;
const int n = 100000;

vector<number> x(n+1);

inline number Harry()
{
    number sum = 0;
    number part = 0;

    for(int i = n; i > 1; --i)
    {
        sum += x[i-1]*(part += x[i]);
    }
    return sum;
}


inline number VladD()
{
    number sum = x[1];
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) sum += x[i];
    sum = sum*sum;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) sum -= x[i]*x[i];
    return sum/2;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i)
        x[i] = rand();

    number sum  = 0;
    {
        muTimer mu;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) sum += VladD();
        cout << sum << endl;
    }
    sum = 0;
    {
        muTimer mu;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) sum += Harry();
        cout << sum << endl;
    }
}
```

Несмотря на просьбы `inline`, встраивать код компилятор не захотел.
При `number = int` получаем, что на небольших размерах переполнение куда раньше наступает в методе @VladD. Зато по скорости оно бьет мой метод:
255 против 462 ms. Но если отключить оптимизацию, то получим обратный эффект - 27 против 18 секунд. Связано с тем, что мой метод оптимизатор никак не может соптимизировать до использования XMM-регистров, в отличие от метода @VladD, где полно кода наподобие

```
$LL4@VladD:
    movups  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [edx+eax*4]
    paddd   xmm2, xmm0
    movups  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [edx+eax*4+16]
    add eax, 8
    paddd   xmm1, xmm0
    cmp eax, 99993              ; 00018699H
    jle SHORT $LL4@VladD
```

Но если взять `number = double`, то оптимизатор начинает оптимизировать соответствующим образом и мой метод, так что получаем 1670 против 750 ms в мою пользу.

Писано просто так, для тех, кому интересно почитать. Никакой особой морали, так сказать, не вижу... Но раз уж сделал - почему не рассказать? :)

Comment: Круто, сравнения — всегда полезно. Можно ещё попробовать прогнать то же на gcc на каком-нибудь online-компиляторе.

Comment: Ещё ради оптимизации, возможно, стоит сдвинуть индексы на 1, чтобы считалось от 0. Это может помочь оптимизатору понять паттерн. (А может и не помочь, если он и так умный.)

Comment: Вот с такими настройками https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyrSs.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NrZQ.png на Visual Studio 2017 мой вариант с `double` вроде снова быстрее. Код: http://ideone.com/kTBpEL

Comment: Возведение в квадрат допускает пирамидальную оптимизацию для длинных чисел (ссылка в примечании к VladD)